# Can I work in the repository in a single user Mercurial workflow?

Tags: mercurial, workflow

I use Mercurial in a single-user workflow to have the option to roll back changes if my coding or writing goes horribly wrong (I primarily use the Stata and R statistics packages and LaTeX). While working only locally, this has been easy since all I have is the main repo.

Recently I have started ssh-ing into a Linux server for more computational power. So far I have been manually copying files back and forth and using Mercurial only locally, but I would like to use Mercurial to take care of this and keep these two workflows synchronized. Also, I like the ability to code both locally (on my laptop or desktop) and on the server.

Do I need to work on a clone of the main repo on the server and keep the main repo untouched? Or can I work directly in the main repo when I am on the server? In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272653/mercurial-between-server-and-local) @gizmo points to [this workflow guide](https://bitbucket.org/segv/hg-website/wiki/Workflows); the "single developer" discussion is helpful, but it's still not clear to me that I can work in the main repo while I'm on the server without causing some major problem that I don't yet understand.

Thanks!

Edit: I should add that I have worked through Joel Spolsky's HgInit.com tutorial and I'm comfortable pushing/pulling/cloning/etc over ssh, but I am still not sure if I can work in the main repo without causing heartache later. Or maybe this is more a philosophical question? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Mercurial is DVCS, it means - in **each location** you have both: local working copy and local repository
- Mercurial is DVCS, it means - you can freely exchange (pull|push) data between repos (*if* they provide remote-access methods).

If you

> comfortable pushing/pulling/cloning/etc over ssh

and **don't forget perform pull|push cycle** around your work *at home* (in order to don't run hg serve at home-host and sync from server as source) you don't get any headache at all with perfect linear aggregated history on each place. And even you forget to sync repo sometimes, you get in worst case two heads later, which you'll be able to merge easy (doesn't know formats of Stata and R data-files, but LaTeX, as text, is mergeable)

Comment: OK, thanks! Reading your answer made me realize that my hesitation about working in the main repo was that in the examples they never `hg update` the main repo. But they don't have to because the `hg push` gives it all the diffs and no one is working the main repo so there's no need to generate the updated files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with working directly in the repository on your server. From Mercurial's point of view, the "main" repository is just another random repository — Mercurial doesn't consider it to be special.

You don't say this directly, but one thing that people ask is "What happens when I push to the server?" The answer is that `hg push` only sends data into the *repository* (the `.hg/` folder). The working copy is not touched on the server when you push to it. Since you push new changesets to the server, you might need to run `hg update` the next time you work on the server. This is just like if you had run `hg pull` on the server — there you'll also merge or update afterwards.

I have this situation all the time: I create a repository at home and clone it to my computer at work. I change files in either location and push/pull between the two repositories. If I need to share my work with others, then I make a repository at Bitbucket and push the code there. That way Bitbucket serves as a nice canonical repository for the code and I typically change the default path to Bitbucket in the repositories at home and at work. So at home I would have:

```
[paths]
default = httsp://bitbucket.org/mg/<repo>/
work = ssh://mg@work/<repo>
```

so that I can do `hg push` to send things to Bitbucket and `hg pull work` to grab things directly from work (in case I forgot to push to Bitbucket before leaving).

Comment: Thanks! The third paragraph and code block are really helpful. I guess my idea of a "main" repo is a bit off. "Main" is really more off a choice.

Comment: @richardh: Exactly, having a "main" repository is just a *convention*.